# Is there an R function to merge two variables into a new one, so that a new cell is written only if a certain entry of another variable is given?

Tags: r, variables, merge

example data structure:

```
dats_long <- data.frame (dv  = c("Unt", "Dis", "Emp"),
                  rating = c(100, 53, 99),
                  unt = c(NA, NA, NA),
                  dis = c(NA, NA, NA),
                  emp = c(NA, NA, NA))
```

There are three measurements per participant (long format), where three DVs were extracted from a vignette survey and the scoring is stored in a separate variable ("rating").

Is there a way to create three new separate DV columns ("unt", "dis", "emp", in the example data structure still NAs) with only the corresponding ratings being written?

Target output:

```
dats_long <- data.frame (dv  = c("Unt", "Dis", "Emp"),
                  rating = c(100, 53, 99),
                  unt = c(100, NA, NA),
                  dis = c(NA, 53, NA),
                  emp = c(NA, NA, 99))
```

Tried the following (example for "dis"), did not write anything

`dats_long %>% mutate(dis =  case_when( dv == "Dis" ~ rating ))`

And the

```
dats_long$dis[dats_long$dv == "Dis"] <- dats_long$rating
```

did not work either as it simply pastes not every third, but every value of "score" for the newly created variable, so that a lag emerges.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi! Could you edit your question to be reproducible? Data structures in images is not very helpful. Editing your question to include example data (in code) will get you the best help in the fastest time. Good luck!

Comment: Is there another column/variable in your dataset that links those three ratings together (i.e., participant ID)? If so, you could use `pivot_wider` to convert from your long format to a wide format.

Comment: Where is the `score` column? What output do you want?

Comment: @jpsmith added the example data in code, thanks for your remark! :-)

Comment: @StewartMacdonald there's a participant id, but when converting to wide-format, the target variables are saved as lists with one written and two empty entries (c(100,NA,NA))

Comment: @Onyambu my bad, it's the rating column I was referring to; the targeted output would be three variables corresponding to the three levels of the "dv", but only matched ratings written (so that, e.g., "unt" would be c(100, -empty-, -empty-), "dis" = c (-empty-, 53, -empty), "emp" = c(-empty-, -empty-, 99))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mutate(dats_long,
      unt = if_else(dv == "Unt", rating, NA_integer_), 
      dis = if_else(dv == "Dis", rating, NA_integer_), 
      emp = if_else(dv == "Emp", rating, NA_integer_))

   dv rating unt dis emp
1 Unt    100 100  NA  NA
2 Dis     53  NA  53  NA
3 Emp     99  NA  NA  99
```

Comment: thanks! tried it and it says 

Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `unt = if_else(dv == "Unt", rating, NA_integer_)`.
Caused by error in `if_else()`:
! Can't combine `true` <character> and `false` <integer>.
Backtrace:
 1. dplyr::mutate(...)
 8. dplyr::if_else(dv == "Unt", rating, NA_integer_)

Comment: You are getting this error because your rating variable is in character format. Is that intended?

Comment: nope, was not intended. changed it and it works - thank you so much!

Comment: If `dv` has much more levels, this method will be hard-coding and cumbersome. There could be other flexible ways that don't depend on the literal levels of `dv`.

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
cbind(dats_long[1:2], model.matrix(~dv:rating+0, dats_long))

   dv rating dvDis:rating dvEmp:rating dvUnt:rating
1 Unt    100            0            0          100
2 Dis     53           53            0            0
3 Emp     99            0           99            0
```

---

```
library(tidyverse)
dats_long[1:2]%>%
   mutate(name = dv, value = rating) %>%
   pivot_wider()

# A tibble: 3 × 5
  dv    rating   Unt   Dis   Emp
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Unt      100   100    NA    NA
2 Dis       53    NA    53    NA
3 Emp       99    NA    NA    99
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```r
library(tidyverse)

dats_long |>
  mutate(across(unt:emp, 
                \(x) tolower(dv) %in% cur_column() |> ifelse(rating, NA)))
#>    dv rating unt dis emp
#> 1 Unt    100 100  NA  NA
#> 2 Dis     53  NA  53  NA
#> 3 Emp     99  NA  NA  99
```